80s movie with helping subterranean alien
I have faint recurring memories  of a character of a movie I've watched when I was a kid. 
He's an alien, and I think the movie passes in an alien planet, the character is good and helps an human I think. 
I think the alien is a kind of subterranean race, he can move under the earth, and the atmosphere of the movie is very much terrain. 
He's humanlike but the face is like a reptile, and lately I thought I've recalled the actor behind the makeup was Kevin Costner, but I didn't find any such film in his filmography. 
I think the movie is from 80s as that was my childhood years.

I believe the movie you're describing is a 1985 science fiction film, called Enemy Mine

Plot:
(IMDB)

In the distant future, as the galaxy is being colonized, humanity goes
  to war against the Dracs, a reptilian race from the planet Draco as
  both races fight over the control of many worlds. During a space
  battle, space pilot Willis Davidge crashes on Fryine IV, a volcanic
planet. Willis finds he isn't alone and finds a Drac named Jeriba
  Shigan has also crashed on the planet. Both stranded on Fryine IV,
  Both Davidge and Jeriba both put aside their differences and their
  hatred for each other as they both tries to survive on the planet,
  where they learn of each others cultures and form a friendship.


Trailer
